# Adapting a Makefile to include SDL2

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, sdl-2

I am compiling a simple program that uses the SDL2 library.
MWE (an oversimplified version of [Lazy Foo's tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/index2.php)):

```
// main.cpp
#include <SDL.h>
int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
  SDL_Window* window = NULL;
  SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
  window = SDL_CreateWindow("The exciting white window", DL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
  screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
  SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB( screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));
  SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
  SDL_Delay(2000);
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
}
```

I would like to adapt the Makefile from [this tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/software-engineering/how-to-write-a-makefile) to handle it.
This is what I tried:

```
program_NAME := main
program_CXX_SRCS := $(wildcard *.cpp)
program_CXX_OBJS := ${program_CXX_SRCS:.cpp=.o}
program_OBJS := $(program_CXX_OBJS)
program_INCLUDE_DIRS := /usr/include/SDL2
program_LIBRARY_DIRS :=
program_LIBRARIES := SDL2

CPPFLAGS += $(foreach includedir,$(program_INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))
LDFLAGS += $(foreach librarydir,$(program_LIBRARY_DIRS),-L$(librarydir))
LDFLAGS += $(foreach library,$(program_LIBRARIES),-l$(library))

.PHONY: all clean distclean

all: $(program_NAME)

$(program_NAME): $(program_OBJS)
    $(LINK.cc) $(program_OBJS) -o $(program_NAME)

clean:
    @- $(RM) $(program_NAME)
    @- $(RM) $(program_OBJS)

distclean: clean
```

However, I get several linker errors:

```
$ make
g++  -I/usr/include/SDL2  -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++  -I/usr/include/SDL2  -lSDL2  main.o -o myprogram
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
main.cpp:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `SDL_GetWindowSurface'
main.cpp:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `SDL_MapRGB'
main.cpp:(.text+0x90): undefined reference to `SDL_FillRect'
main.cpp:(.text+0x9c): undefined reference to `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface'
main.cpp:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to `SDL_Delay'
main.cpp:(.text+0xb2): undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow'
main.cpp:(.text+0xb7): undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:18: recipe for target 'myprogram' failed
make: *** [myprogram] Error 1
```

I understood from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68922/cant-compile-program-that-uses-sdl-after-upgrade-to-11-10-undefined-reference) that the order of the arguments now matters. Invoking

```
$ g++ -I/usr/include/SDL2 -c -o main.o main.cpp
$ g++ main.o -lSDL2 -o main
```

directly from the command line works.

So finally my **question**: what is the *correct* way of adapting the Makefile? (By "correct" I mean avoiding the type of pitfalls the Makefile tutorial above mentions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in the tutorial makefile you have found. To fix the makefile, replace the line:

```
LDFLAGS += $(foreach library,$(program_LIBRARIES),-l$(library))
```

with:

```
LDLIBS += $(foreach library,$(program_LIBRARIES),-l$(library))
```

and replace the line:

```
$(LINK.cc) $(program_OBJS) -o $(program_NAME)
```

with:

```
$(LINK.cc) $(program_OBJS) -o $(program_NAME) $(LDLIBS)
```

or in more normal style:

```
$(LINK.cc) $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)
```

(See [10.5.3 Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html)
in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html))

The error in the tutorial makefile is that is that it doesn't correctly
employ (or explain) the canonical make-variables `LDFLAGS` and `LDLIBS`. It 
bundles all of the linker's library options (`-l<name>`) into the value of `LDFLAGS`.
They are not supposed to go there. They should go in the value of `LDLIBS`.

The predefined make variable `LINK.cc` expands to:

```
LINK.cc = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)
```

which does *not* include `$(LDLIBS)`, precisely because the GNU linker, as
used in most GCC distributions (including yours), requires object files to appear
earlier in the linkage sequence than the libraries they depend on, and will
ignore a library at a position in the sequence where it does not resolve any symbol 
references that the linker *already needs to resolve*.

If `LDLIBS` is correctly employed for the `-l`
options, and correctly employed in a linkage recipe - as in the corrected linkage recipe above
- then all libraries will safely appear after all object files.

By bundling `-l` options into `$(LDFLAGS)`, the tutorial gets all the libraries
before all the object files; so in your linkage, `-lSDL2` is ignored and your
linkage fails as observed.

Here is a crib to the canonical GNU make-variables that are typically
operative in C or C++ compilation and linkage:

`CC`        Command that invokes your C compiler (default `cc`)

`CXX`       Command that invokes your C++ compiler (default `g++`)

`CPPFLAGS`  Your options for the C/C++ preprocessor

`CFLAGS`    Your options for the C compiler

`CXXFLAGS`  Your options for the C++ compiler

`LDFLAGS`   Your options for linkage, *excluding libraries and library (-`l`) options*

`LDLIBS`    Your linkage libraries or library (`-l`) options

The default value is empty unless otherwise specified.

See [10.2 Catalogue of Built-In Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules)
to learn how these variables work in make's builtin rules. Or save the output of
`make --print-data-base` to a file and study it.